# Android App causes sort of reboot

Tags: java, android

When exiting my app it is causing devices to show their initial turning on animation and go to the home screen. I have a feeling it is something to do with memory. As it only happens when a user goes from one activity to another and repeats like this

A -> B

B -> A

Repeat.

The information changes each time and I have set A and B to close when another of the same has been opened. So a user can only go back one. But if you repeat this process around 20 times. When you come to go back it will go to the home app screen then if you leave the app do this odd behavious.

By looking at logcat it seems to repeat the block below the number of times you went from A to B. I have no idea what this is or why it is running so many times.

```
11-20 15:47:40.236: DEBUG/WifiStateTracker(1505): get mPhoneStateListener
11-20 15:47:41.087: DEBUG/SensorService(1505): enable: get sensor name = MPL accel
11-20 15:47:41.087: DEBUG/Sensors(1505): handle : 4 en: 1, v010.0 - Try to resolve lock issue
11-20 15:47:41.087: DEBUG/Sensors(1505): lock_status = 58
11-20 15:47:41.087: DEBUG/Sensors(1505): Andy: MPLSensor::enable: lock1
11-20 15:47:41.087: DEBUG/Sensors(1505): mEnabled = 0x10
11-20 15:47:41.087: DEBUG/Sensors(1505): set_power_states++: enabled_sensors: 16 dmp_started: 0
11-20 15:47:41.087: DEBUG/Sensors(1505): Before if statment: cs:0 rs:1 en_ped:0 da_ped:0 en_g:0 da_g:0
11-20 15:47:41.087: DEBUG/Sensors(1505): STOP timerirq_1
11-20 15:47:41.107: DEBUG/Sensors(1505): Starting DMP
11-20 15:47:41.127: INFO/(1505): mpu3050_resume: Resuming to 0070
11-20 15:47:41.127: DEBUG/Sensors(1505): Exit: Starting DMP
11-20 15:47:41.127: DEBUG/Sensors(1505): set_power_states--
11-20 15:47:41.127: DEBUG/Sensors(1505): Andy: MPLSensor::enable: unlock1
11-20 15:47:41.127: DEBUG/Sensors(1505): MPLSensor::enable--1
11-20 15:47:41.127: DEBUG/SensorService(1505): SensorDevice::activate--: handle = 0x4, enabled = 0x1
11-20 15:47:41.127: DEBUG/SensorService(1505): enable: sensor->activate return value = 0x0
11-20 15:47:41.127: DEBUG/SensorService(1505): enable: calling mActiveSensors.add(handle, rec) = (0x4, 0x7a40e8)
11-20 15:47:41.127: DEBUG/SensorService(1505): enable: mActiveConnections.indexOf(connection) = 0x0
11-20 15:47:41.127: DEBUG/SensorService(1505): pid=1505, uid=1000
11-20 15:47:41.127: DEBUG/SensorService(1505): disable: get sensor name = MPL accel
11-20 15:47:41.127: DEBUG/SensorService(1505): disable: sensor = 0x326a98
11-20 15:47:41.127: DEBUG/Sensors(1505): handle : 4 en: 0, v010.0 - Try to resolve lock issue
11-20 15:47:41.127: DEBUG/Sensors(1505): lock_status = 63
11-20 15:47:41.127: DEBUG/Sensors(1505): Andy: MPLSensor::enable: lock1
11-20 15:47:41.127: WARN/MPL-sup(1505): MLGetAKMComassStatus, gAKMCompassStatus = 0
11-20 15:47:41.127: DEBUG/Sensors(1505): mEnabled = 0x0
11-20 15:47:41.127: DEBUG/Sensors(1505): set_power_states++: enabled_sensors: 0 dmp_started: 1
11-20 15:47:41.127: DEBUG/Sensors(1505): Before if statment: cs:0 rs:0 en_ped:0 da_ped:0 en_g:0 da_g:0
11-20 15:47:41.127: DEBUG/Sensors(1505): Stopping DMP
11-20 15:47:41.127: INFO/(1505): mpu3050_suspend: suspending sensors to 0000
11-20 15:47:41.127: INFO/(1505): mpu3050_suspend: Will resume next to 0070
11-20 15:47:41.127: DEBUG/Sensors(1505): inside if(s_use_timerirq)
11-20 15:47:41.157: DEBUG/Sensors(1505): set_power_states--
11-20 15:47:41.157: DEBUG/Sensors(1505): Andy: MPLSensor::enable: unlock1
11-20 15:47:41.157: DEBUG/Sensors(1505): MPLSensor::enable--1
11-20 15:47:41.157: DEBUG/SensorService(1505): SensorDevice::activate--: handle = 0x4, enabled = 0x0
11-20 15:47:41.157: DEBUG/SensorService(1505): pid=1505, uid=1000
11-20 15:47:41.167: DEBUG/SensorService(1505): enable: get sensor name = MPL accel
11-20 15:47:41.167: DEBUG/Sensors(1505): handle : 4 en: 1, v010.0 - Try to resolve lock issue
11-20 15:47:41.167: DEBUG/Sensors(1505): lock_status = 58
11-20 15:47:41.167: DEBUG/Sensors(1505): Andy: MPLSensor::enable: lock1
11-20 15:47:41.167: DEBUG/Sensors(1505): mEnabled = 0x10
11-20 15:47:41.167: DEBUG/Sensors(1505): set_power_states++: enabled_sensors: 16 dmp_started: 0
11-20 15:47:41.167: DEBUG/Sensors(1505): Before if statment: cs:0 rs:1 en_ped:0 da_ped:0 en_g:0 da_g:0
11-20 15:47:41.167: DEBUG/Sensors(1505): STOP timerirq_1
11-20 15:47:41.187: DEBUG/Sensors(1505): Starting DMP
11-20 15:47:41.207: INFO/(1505): mpu3050_resume: Resuming to 0070
```

EDIT:
LogCat output regarding DB's

```
11-20 17:47:44.779: DEBUG/Database(6695): dbopen(): path = /data/data/com.package.here/databases/db, flag = 2, file size = 78848
11-20 17:47:44.779: DEBUG/Database(6695): dbopen(): path = /data/data/com.package.here/databases/db, mode: wal, disk free size: 3792 M, handle: 0x3e6cb8
11-20 17:47:44.839: DEBUG/Database(6695): dbclose(): path = /data/data/com.package.here/databases/db, handle = 0x3e6cb8
```

Comment: what are you doing in these activities? it must be related to that. I am thinking of any external resources you might be using: databases, sensors, camera ... these may not be closed automatically

Comment: database is the only thing. I shall take a look. The odd thing is I cannot replicate this on all devices only on some.

Comment: try closing the database in the activities onPause() or at least onStop(). Android does manage the activity lifecycle for you but not the database connections. also: if you cannot reproduce this on all devices, how about the emulator?

Comment: I have found something interesting that is happening on both of the activities. It seems to log 2 opens and one close, but I am not familiar enough with logcat to know if this is ok. Take a look at the revisions above